# How can I assign a return value to a function input via short variable declaration in Golang?

Tags: go

Consider following code snippet...

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(".", os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
```

In-order to check for error & proceed, we need to have something like..

```
func checkerr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

and then call this tiny function to validate the error. For eg..

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(".", os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
checkerr(err)
files, err := f.Readdirnames(0)
checkerr(err)
```

While this works, I'm looking for a shortcut to directly call `checkerr()` during initialisation phase itself. See below...

```
f, checkerr(err) := os.OpenFile(".", os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
```

Is it possible using native Golang constructs?

Comment: this reading is a good one: https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat after me: "It's idiomatic Go to check for errors." The following is *not* bad code, even if it's not the DRYest.

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(".", os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
files, err := f.Readdirnames(0)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```